# SQL CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

There are  two fields (BIT data type) in my database table PE and PER i need to write a sql case statement to perform the following task.

when PER=0 then print 'Not Required'
when PER=1 then check  if PE=0 then print 'Not Completed' when PE=1 print 'Completed'

following is the query i have tried and which is not working

```
CASE pc.PER WHEN '0' THEN 'Not Required'
                                    WHEN '1' THEN (CASE pc.PE WHEN '0' THEN 'Not Completed'
                       WHEN '1' THEN 'Completed') end as ab
```

Comment: Have you added all the needed tables in the `FROM` clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be easier to write it as:

```
CASE
    WHEN pc.PER = '0' THEN 'Not Required'
    WHEN pc.PER = '1' AND pc.PE = '0' THEN 'Not Completed'
    ELSE 'Completed'
END
```

Alternatively you would have to add `END` after `... WHEN '1' THEN 'Completed'` in your query:

```
CASE pc.PER WHEN '0' THEN 'Not Required'
            WHEN '1' THEN (CASE pc.PE WHEN '0' THEN 'Not Completed'
                                      WHEN '1' THEN 'Completed'
                           END)
END AS ab
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an end.

```
CASE pc.PER 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Required'
    WHEN 1 THEN 
        CASE pc.PE 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Completed'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Completed'
        END
END as ab
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following statement instead:

```
CASE WHEN pc.PER =0 THEN 'Not Required'  
     WHEN pc.PER =1 THEN 
         CASE   WHEN pc.PE = 0 THEN 'Not Completed'
                WHEN pc.PE = 1 THEN 'Completed' 
     End 
End as ab
```